# Search bar with suggestions with nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, search

I'm developing a web application using nodejs, express and mongodb. I need a search bar giving me suggestions from a collection in the mongo database while I'm typing. What I'm searching for is the search bar implemented in [this web page](https://www.gsmarena.com/compare.php3). How can I implement it?

Answer (score 1):

For a simple implementation, just send a request to your server containing the search keyword, example : "mobile"

Then in mongo, target the fields wanted with a regex then return the result.

Front:

```
// on input change
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://searchuri",
    data: { search: mysearchinput }
})
.fail(function(err) {
    console.log(err.responseJSON);
})
.done(function(data) {
   // do stg with your datas
});
```

Back:

```
   Datas.find({ productname: { $regex : ".*"+ req.query.search +".*", $options:'i' } }, function(err, result){

     return res.status(200).json({result: result})

  });
```