# How to do "smart search" in JSON File?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, search, ecmascript-6

Suppose I have a JSON object such as `[{
address: "Amber 21, Pallet Town, Johto"
value: 8
},
address: "Red 12, Vermilion City, Hoenn"
value: 9
]`

A user type `Amber street, Johto` in the form.
I'd like to do "smart search" to match the one with the most resemblance (in other words like `the best score` if we talk about machine learning) and get the result which is `8`.
Is there any module which does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's a module which does that really well.

Checkout [fusejs](http://fusejs.io/)

Answer (score 1):

For a simple implementation, just send a request to your server containing the search keyword, example : "mobile"

Then in mongo, target the fields wanted with a regex then return the result.

Front:

```
// on input change
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://searchuri",
    data: { search: mysearchinput }
})
.fail(function(err) {
    console.log(err.responseJSON);
})
.done(function(data) {
   // do stg with your datas
});
```

Backend:

```
Datas.find({ productname: { $regex : ".*"+ req.query.search +".*", $options:'i' } }, function(err, result){

     return res.status(200).json({result: result})

  });
```

Reference : [Search bar with suggestions with nodejs and mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48624849/search-bar-with-suggestions-with-nodejs-and-mongodb)

Comment: I'm not talking about database.. it's just a local JSON file.. So, is there any way to do the search without putting it on the database? Besides, MongoDB search uses regex, not the scoring system based on the resemblance (like machine learning). So, sorry, you didn't answer my question